# How to dynamically keep track of texture units in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I currently creating a texture class for a project I am working on and I am trying to create things well from the start to prevent future headaches.

Currently the way I would load a texture's information to the GPU would be as follows:

```
void Texture::load_to_GPU(GLuint program)
{
    if(program == Rendering_Handler->shading_programs[1].programID)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    glUseProgram(program);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

    GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "text");
    if(loc == GL_INVALID_VALUE || loc==GL_INVALID_OPERATION)
    {
        cerr << "Error returned when trying to find texture uniform."
            << "\nuniform: text"
            << "Error num: " << loc
            << endl;
        return;
    }

    glUniform1i(loc,0);
}
```

I however would like to be able to determine the texture unit dynamically.

For example, rather than hard coding the uniform name "text", I would like to pass the string as an argument, and do something similar to `glGetUniformLocation()` but for texture units.

In other words I want to select the texture unit to which the texture is to be bound dynamically rather than hard coding it.

For this I need to find a texture unit that is not currently in use, ideally from smallest to largest texture unit.

What set of OpenGL functions could I use to achieve this behaviour?

EDIT:

An important tool I need to achieve the behaviour I want, which I believe is not clear from the original post is:

Once a texture unit is bound to a sampler uniform, I'd like to be able to get the texture unit bound to the uniform.

So if texture unit 5 is bound to the uniform "sampler2d texture_5"

I want a function that takes the uniform label and returns the texture unit bound to that label.

Comment: You could just manually keep track of occupied texture units. Or you could use `glGet(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D)` to check whether a unit is free or not.

Comment: The most efficient way to do this would be to use a bitmask, but then that requires me to properly implement a static method and variable to keep track of occupied and unoccupied texture units. And I intend to multithread my application in the future, so this can potentially become a lot fo trouble. If OpenGL itself can track which texture units are active or not, that would simplify the process

Comment: As I said, you can check whether a unit is occupied or not. But looping through them to find a free one doesn't seem efficient. If you want mulithreading, you have more problems, since only one thread can interact with GL context at a time, and you need to manually specify which thread is that. Also, `glGetUniformLocation` returns `-1` in case of a error, not the error codes. Those codes will be returned by `glGetError()`.

Comment: That is not entirely correct, there may only be one context per thread, but information can be shared across multiple contexts. I have multithreaded OpenGL before, so i know it's very doable, you just need to be careful.

Comment: @Makogan: "*information can be shared across multiple contexts*" Each context has independent context state. They can share the same objects, but they don't share the context bindings for them. So if you bind a texture to unit 0 on context 0, that has no effect on unit 0 of context 1, even if the two contexts share objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have all texture binding/unbinding wrapped.

If so, you can use following approach to allocate and free texture units in O(1) time, using O(n) memory.

(I've not seen this approach anywhere else and don't know the name of this data structure. If anyone knows what's it called, I'd appreciate the information.)

```
constexpr int capacity = 64; // A total number of units.
int size = 0; // Amount of allocated units.

std::vector<int> pool, indices;

void init()
{
    pool.resize(capacity);
    std::iota(pool.begin(), pool.end(), 0);
    indices.resize(capacity);
    std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);
}

int alloc()
{
    if (size >= capacity)
        return -1; // No more texture units.
    return pool[size++];
}

void free(int unit)
{
    // assert(indices[unit] < size) - if this fails, then you have a double free
    size--;
    int last_unit = pool[size];
    std::swap(pool[indices[unit]], pool[size]);
    std::swap(indices[unit], indices[last_unit]);
}
```

Comment: Although i like your approach since it is very elegant. I ebleive that using a bitmask ends up being more efficient, since, although you would need to do a linear search in hte number of bits which is O(n), since we are dealing with very small data sates (<64) and bit operations are very efficient, the bitmask approach ends up having a comparable run time with less use of RAM.


Is it possible to get the texture unit bound to a sampler uniform?

Comment: @Makogan `glGetUniformiv()` should work. If you end up profiling both approaches, I'd be interested in knowing the results. No idea what's faster.

Comment: How does this deal with the fact that multiple textures can be bound to the same texture unit?

Comment: @NicolBolas I will just follow your advice and forget that that can be done:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990228/using-different-texture-types-in-same-texture-unit-at-the-same-time-in-shader?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa